# Trigonometric identities

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

Can you help me to solve this question please

Use the formula
$$\cos \theta =\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}$$
to obtain the identity
$$\cos (5\theta) =\frac{\cos (5\theta) + 5 \cos (3\theta) + 10 \cos \theta}{16}.$$

Comment: Please indicate what you have already tried doing and where you ran into difficulty.

Answer (score 3):

The correct identity, with proof, is

$$\cos^5\theta=\left(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}\over2\right)^5={e^{5i\theta}+5e^{4i\theta}e^{-i\theta}+10e^{3i\theta}e^{-2i\theta}+10e^{2i\theta}e^{-3i\theta}+5e^{i\theta}e^{-4i\theta}+e^{-5i\theta}\over32}
={e^{5i\theta}+e^{-5i\theta}\over32}+5{e^{3i\theta}+e^{-3i\theta}\over32}+10{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}\over32}={\cos5\theta+5\cos3\theta+10\cos\theta\over16}$$